# What is the base class of master page & User Control in asp.net c#?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

What is the base class of master page & User Control in asp.net c#?

Comment: Why not create one of each and look at the source code?

Comment: You can see this quite easily in Visual Studio. Where it says "System.Web.UI.MasterPage" put your cursor on MasterPage, press F12 or choose "Go To Definition" from the context menu. Repeat as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inheritance tree of a MasterPage is:

```
System.Object
 System.Web.UI.Control
  System.Web.UI.TemplateControl
   System.Web.UI.UserControl
    System.Web.UI.MasterPage
```

(taken from [MasterPage class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.masterpage.aspx))

From that you can see what's confirmed on [UserControl class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol.aspx), that UserControl also inherits from TemplateControl, then Control and finally Object.

Answer (score 0):

System.Web.UI.MasterPage for MasterPages and System.Web.UI.UserControl for User Controls.

Please let me know if that doesn't answer you question...

Answer (score 0):

MasterPage inherits from System.Web.UI.UserControl.

UserControl inherits from System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.